# Is the max-min a convex combination of the minima?

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ be convex continuous functions defined in a convex compact domain $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, and let
$$
x_i := \arg\min_{x\in C} f_i(x).
$$

Let $g$ be a convex function defined by $g(x) := \max_{i}f_i(x)$, and let
$$
y := \arg\min_{x\in C} g(x).
$$

Is $y$ a convex combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?

Here is an illustration of the question for $n=2$ functions in dimension $d=1$:

[image]

EDIT: We can assume that $C$ is compact and the functions $f_i$ are continuous.

Comment: Do we have any other asusmptions on $C$ or the $f_i$? e.g. is $C$ closed or compact? are $f_i$ lower semicontinuous or coercive?

Comment: @Zim we can assume that $C$ is compact and that the $f_i$ are continuous. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimiser of the maximum $y$ does not have to be a convex combination of the $x_i$. Take $f_1(u,v)=(u-v)^2+\frac{v^2}{100}$, $f_2(u,v)=(u+v-1)^2+\frac{v^2}{100}$. That is, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are elongated valleys in different directions, where the floor of each valley has a slight depression on the $u$-axis. The minimum of $\max\{f_1,f_2\}$ lies in the intersection of the 'valleys', off the $u$-axis.